# FireMonkey - drawing a 1 pixel line without anti-aliasing in Windows

Tags: delphi, line, firemonkey

I had no success trying to draw a 1-pixel line. I tried setting the `Quality` param in the form to all the three available options, but this does not change the result: always get a line with anti-aliasing. Conversely, somehow, the `tRectangle` class draws a clean 1-pixel width border, meaning that is possible to disable the anti-aliasing mode. The question is how. Follows an example of the code I'm using:

```
procedure tMyLine.Paint;
begin
  with Canvas do begin
       Stroke.Cap       := Flat;
       Stroke.Color     := tAlphaColor.Blue;
       Stroke.Join      := Miter;
       Stroke.Kind      := Solid;
       Stroke.Thickness := 1;
       BeginScene;
         DrawLine (tPointF (10, 10), tPointF (100, 10), 1);
       EndScene;
  end;
end;
```

`Thickness` less than one does not work either.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg. Thanks for your comment. Your code works fine for dotted lines, but for solid lines, with a diagonal slope, the result is an anti-aliased line.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg. I apologize. in fact, `tRectangle` renders anti-aliasing lines when rotated any angle not multiple of  90. I simply don't get why is so difficult to suppress the anti-alias.

Comment: Did you actually try with `Quality=HighPerformance` on the form?

Comment: @Tom Brunberg. Yes. As I stated at the header of the question:  "I tried setting the Quality param in the form to all the three available options, but this does not change the result".

Comment: Ok, user, then I need to ask which version you are working with, because in XE7 it makes a difference.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg. I'm using RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo. Please tell me in wich way, changing the `Quality` param in the form, makes any difference. Thanks.

Comment: FMX.Forms.TForm.Quality is of type `TCanvasQuality`, defined as: `TCanvasQuality = (SystemDefault, HighPerformance, HighQuality);` The `SystemDefault` setting means whatever is set as default for the platform the program is running on. The `HighPerformance` setting means as fast as possible, NO antialiasing. `HighQuality` means softer, 'unjagged' because of antialiasing. Ergo, if you want no antialiasing, select `HighPerformance`.

Answer (score 1):

With these settings (deviating from defaults) of the form and the paintbox:
(btw, with Delphi 10.1 Berlin, I don't have Tokyo installed)

```
object Form24: TForm24
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form24'
  ClientHeight = 216
  ClientWidth = 311
  Quality = HighPerformance
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object PaintBox1: TPaintBox
    Position.X = 8.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 8.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 200.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 200.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    OnPaint = PaintBox1Paint
  end
```

Note: `Quality = HighPerformance`, not `HighQuality`

the following code

```
procedure TForm24.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas);
var
  a: integer;
begin
  Canvas.BeginScene;
  try
    Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
    Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
    Canvas.Stroke.Dash := TStrokeDash.solid;

    for a := 0 to 10 do
      Canvas.DrawLine(PointF(a * 20, 0), PointF(a * 20, 200), 1);

    for a := 0 to 10 do
      Canvas.DrawLine(PointF(0, a * 20 + 0), PointF(200, a * 20), 1);


    Canvas.DrawLine(PointF(0, 0), PointF(200, 200), 1);
    Canvas.DrawEllipse(RectF(5, 5, 195, 195), 1);

    Canvas.Stroke.Dash := TStrokeDash.Solid;
    Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Red;
    Canvas.DrawRect(RectF(5, 5, 195, 195), 0, 0, [], 1);
  finally
    Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
end;
```

produces this result

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this for vertical and horizontal lines by setting coordinates to integer + 0.5. It seems that if you use integer coordinates then you're placing the line on a pixel boundary but by adding 0.5 you place the line in the middle of the pixel.

DrawLine (tPointF (10.5, 10.5), tPointF (100.5, 10.5), 1);